# Vue - variáveis de instância não funciona

Tags: vue.js

Estou migrando meu projeto para vue-cli e as variaveis de instância não estão funcionando:

main.js

```
Vue.$storage = Vue.prototype.$storage = new SecureLs({encodingType: 'rc4', isCompression: true, encryptionSecret: 'fasdfasdf'})
Vue.$defines = Vue.prototype.$defines = Defines
```

app.vue

```
computed: {
    user_email: () => {
      console.log(this.$defines) // undefined
      console.log(this.$storage) // undefined
      return ''
    }
  },
```

Porém no template funciona corretamente:

```
{{ $storage.get('user') }}
{{ $defines }}
```

O mesmo problema ocorre com $store, $nextTick, etc..

**EDIT**: Mesmo fazendo a instalação via plugin, o problema continua:

```
<template>
  <span class="caption">{{ $storage }}</span> <!-- Apresenta o valor na tela corretamente -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted: () => {
    console.log(this.$storage)  // Retorna UNDEFINED
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Olá. Por favor poste a solução lá embaixo, como resposta, e remova da pergunta. Agora, muito estranho isso...

Comment: Está na documentação: [**Instance Lifecycle Hooks**](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) / [**Ciclo de Vida da Instância**](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Ciclo-de-Vida-da-Instancia).

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEMA E SOLUÇÃO**

Descobri que o problema é o padrão ES6 para declaração de funções:

Funciona:

```
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$storage)
}

mounted: function() {
  console.log(this.$storage)
}
```

Não funciona

```
mounted: () => {
   console.log(this.$storage)
}
```

Quando se utiliza Arrow functions ( () => {} ) em JS, o valor de this é referente ao escopo pai da função. Todas as funções que utilizam this, obrigatoriamente precisam ser funções normais (function(){}).

Answer (score -1):

Escreva seus próprios [plugins](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Escrevendo-um-Plugin) e utilize junto com o Vue.
Escrevi um exemplo funcionando com o CodeSanbox, da uma olhada clicando [aqui](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-cli-bchbf?fontsize=14).

***./store.js***

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    hello: "Hello from vuex"
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {}
});
```

***./plugins/storage.js***

```
import SecureLS from "secure-ls";

export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$storage = new SecureLS({
      encodingType: "rc4",
      isCompression: true,
      encryptionSecret: "fasdfasdf"
    });
  }
};
```

***main.js***

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import Storage from "./plugins/storage";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(Storage);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

***./views/Home.vue***

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h1>{{ $store.state.hello }}</h1>
    <br>
    <h3>My Plugin Secure LS</h3>
    <b>{{ $storage.get("demo") }}</b>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
  created() {
    this.$storage.set("demo", { data: "Hello from Local Storage" });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, realmente o problema não está no código... fiz os testes no CodeSanbox, e todos funcionaram.. e copiei seu código para o meu ambiente... e não funciona...

Comment: Vou recriar todo o ambiente. Valeu

Comment: Descobri o problema... não era ambiente. O erro corre quando utilizamos funções no padrão ES6... mounted: function() e mounted() funciona normalmente... porém mounted: () => não funciona.